# Filter middleware js

Tags: express, model-view-controller, middleware

I need to add into my MVC js project a middleware filter which will transfer control to the controller which will do some actions if the filter condition is false and render a special page if a condition is true (but not giving the controll to the controller). It must be a middleware which executes before the controller logic and it SHOULD NOT BE a function in the controller.

Here i have a route which now just executes a download method in the controller.

```
if (config.common.zoneName === 'main') {
router.get('/book/:itemid', new 
DownloadController(ResourceRepo).download);
}
```

I need to add there some logic, for example

```
if (itemid > 10){
//render some special page
} 
//execute download method on the same controller
}
```

In the real task condition is preety complex (such as getting the request IP and checking a field in a datadase with the same IP). So the condition is not an inline function but some complex method.
How can i do that using expressjs middleware? 
Many thanks :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to do something like this:

```
if (config.common.zoneName === 'main') {
  router.get('/book/:itemid', 
    (req, res, next) => {
      if (req.params.itemid > 10){
        //render some special page
      } 
      //execute download method on the same controller
    },
    new DownloadController(ResourceRepo).download);
}
```

Comment: Yea, thanks, but i'm a little bit new to dynamic PLs so consider that this cpde should work but if the if condition is true will the download method execute? Cause i need this middleware to prevent download method from executing if condition is false ( and the condition itself should be some kind of a complex boolean function which refers to a database and checks some field there (but as i was said a middleware)).

Comment: If you want to prevent thw download is executed when the if condition succes, you just need to put the download Code into an else statement. Also you can put a 'return next()' at the end of the if. Make sure your middleware method always execute next() at the end of the execution if everything was right, that's what allow to pasa yo Next step of the pipeline of the middleware